Installing VirtualBox from .deb and version changes in Software Center after removing old version of VirtualBox
On my desktop machine (22.04 Budgie), VirtualBox 6.1.50 would no longer launch one of my VMs which runs Windows 10. I realized VirtualBox 7.0.20 was now out so I decided to upgrade.
I removed (apt remove --purge virtualbox*) VirtualBox 6.1.50 and then tried to install from the VirtualBox 7.0.20 .deb file I downloaded from their website. However, when I installed 7.0.20, I ended up with 6.1.50 installed. Strange.
So, I uninstalled it using the Software Center. Rebooted (habit). Then tried to install again. This is when I saw something I do not understand at all.
I right click on the file (virtualbox-7.0_7.0.20-163906~Ubuntu~noble_amd64) and choose Software Install. Then the Software Center opens with VirtualBox ready to install. This is where it gets stranger.
When the Software Center opens, I see this version (7.0.20):

However, if I wait for about 10-20 seconds (not installing, just waiting after opening it in Software Center), the version magically changes to my previously installed version (6.1.50):

Clearly, I would like to install 7.0.20. I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Any ideas?

Is the only way to re-install my OS? I guess this is a good time to upgrade to 24.04. Still, it seems there should be a way to fix VirtualBox.

I gave up and installed Ubuntu Budgie 24.04. Now, VirtualBox works fine.
